# cmake generators build for windows platform

Tags: windows, compiling, cmake

Hi I want to build my project for windows from Ubuntu, but I can't find the generators for my `cmake` instalation.

i run:

```
$ cmake -G
```

and have this:

```
Generators
  Unix Makefiles               = Generates standard UNIX makefiles.
  Ninja                        = Generates build.ninja files.
  Watcom WMake                 = Generates Watcom WMake makefiles.
  CodeBlocks - Ninja           = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles  = Generates CodeBlocks project files.
  CodeLite - Ninja             = Generates CodeLite project files.
  CodeLite - Unix Makefiles    = Generates CodeLite project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Ninja       = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
                               = Generates Sublime Text 2 project files.
  Kate - Ninja                 = Generates Kate project files.
  Kate - Unix Makefiles        = Generates Kate project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja         = Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles= Generates Eclipse CDT 4.0 project files.
  KDevelop3                    = Generates KDevelop 3 project files.
  KDevelop3 - Unix Makefiles   = Generates KDevelop 3 project files.
```

this is my first time doing this kind of things an I don´t know if I have to install something, or even if I can´t do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Windows (Visual Studio) generators are only available on Windows CMake builds.

There's some evidence to this limitation in CMake's [source code](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Source/cmake.cxx), see  `CreateDefaultGlobalGenerator` for example.

If you really have to generate Windows projects on Ubuntu, you could use Windows CMake build on a Windows emulator like `wine`.